# AngularJS 1.8.1 Component not loading in Internet Explorer

Tags: angularjs, user-interface, internet-explorer, components, angularjs-1.7

This is my first time using angular js components and everything works fine in all browsers except Internet explorer. I have added meta tag  . Is there a way to make the components render in ie. I have a component  which is not loading any HTML content.

Kindly suggest a workaround.

Comment: Which version of IE are you using? Is there any error in console in IE? Please provide [a minimal code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which can **reproduce** the issue so that we can have a test and see how to help. We can't locate the issue with only the above description.

Comment: I am using IE 10. After all these hours of troubleshooting I have found that template literals are the issue. I have used backtick strings which creates this issue. @Yu Zhou Do you know a way to transpile es6 strings .. I have tried babel in my html file.. but no luck

Comment: Sounds like you have solved the issue. You can post the solution for this issue and mark your answer as an accepted answer after 48 hrs, when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: @Yu Zhou .. I have found the issue.. but still searching for a possibility to use backtick that works in all browsers. Is there a way to transpile backtick strings to es2015 using CDN. Please help if you have confronted a similar issue.